# Computing $\langle x_ix_{i+1}\rangle$ in a polymer chain

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics

I have a basic question about 1D polymer chains consisting of $N$ rods of length $l$. I have read about ideal chains where we assume that the polymer has zero Hamiltonian. This can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_chain) Now, suppose instead $H(x) = nV$ where $n$ is the number of bends in the polymer $x$ and consider the canonical ensemble of the system. Let $x_i$ be the individual displacements of the ith link in the chain; i.e. $x_i = \pm l$. I curious how we determine the average value $\langle x_ix_{i+1}\rangle$.

I have that the probability of a state $x$ of a system is given by $\rho(x) = \frac{1}{Z_\beta}e^{-\beta H(x)}$. That being said, do we have something like
$$\langle x_i x_{i+1}\rangle = l^2\Big(\frac{1-e^{-\beta V}}{1+e^{-\beta V}}\Big)$$
from saying that the probability of a bend in $x_i x_{i+1}$ is $e^{-\beta V}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your answer is correct. If you need more formal solution, then let's introduce Ising variables $s_i = x_{i+1}/x_i = \pm 1$. Energy has the following expression in terms of this variables
$$
H(x) = nV = \sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\frac{1-s_i}2
$$
The variables $x_1, s_1,\ldots,s_{N-1}$ are not subject to any restrictions. Hence the probability factorizes
$$
\rho(x) = C\prod_{i=1}^{N-1} e^{\beta V s_i/2}
$$
and gives
$$
\langle s_i \rangle = \frac{e^{\beta V/2} - e^{-\beta V/2}}{e^{\beta V/2} + e^{-\beta V/2}}
$$
Finally,
$$
\langle x_i x_{i+1}\rangle = l^2 \langle s_i \rangle = l^2 \frac{1 - e^{-\beta V}}{1 + e^{-\beta V}}.
$$

Another method is to introduce Ising variables $\sigma_i = x_i/l$. Getting a solution this way takes a little longer, but you can also solve a more general problem about the polymer chain that the force acts on.

Comment: Thank you for the response!